# How to achieve a marquee text in pascal or any programming language?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pascal, marquee

I remember once in school we had the task of programming a marquee text in pascal, that is a text that moves from left to right. I also remember that I did not have the slightest clue how to do this. Nowadays I'm still not a good programmer, and wanted to ask you guys how you would do it - without any sort of libraries of course.

I thought of putting any letter in an array value and then for example every second move the array values one position to the right or something. Don't know if thats a good "algorithm".

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example in python I would do :

```
>>> L='ABCDEFGH'
>>> l=len(L)
>>> i=0
>>> while(i<20):
    print L[i%l:]+L[:i%l]
    i+=1
```

You just move the starting letter from left to right (respecting the number of letters that's why I take the modulo (%)) and you move the rest of the string on the other side.

and you would get :

```
ABCDEFGH
BCDEFGHA
CDEFGHAB
DEFGHABC
EFGHABCD
FGHABCDE
GHABCDEF
HABCDEFG
ABCDEFGH
BCDEFGHA
CDEFGHAB
...
```

Hope I understood your problem.

Comment: that's probably the easiest way of doing it, thanks! but how would you do this interactively, not with print but with only one line like the <marquee> in html?

Comment: @Ian, In the while loop, instead of the print, you would have to show up a message box and update the message at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

For a form applicaiton, I can suggest creating a thread that moves the text label through x axis with specified interval.